# How to apply searching with case column

Tags: mysql

I have a user table in which i have three fields id,email,u_firstname,u_status
in which i have to apply searching on this table with case function in where condition.

```
users table structure
...........................................................................
id    email                       u_firstname    status(0=inactive,1=active)
...........................................................................
1     varunjoshi919@gmail.com      varun              1
2     abc@gmail.com                abc                0
```

I write the below query in which i have used case function of mysql
which works like that if 0 is come then inactive comes as a string or 
if 1 is come from db then active will show like this

Query

```
SELECT `id`,`email`,`u_firstname`,case u_status when '0' then 'inactive' when '1' then 'active' end as status FROM `users`
```

After running the above query i got this output
  from users table structure

```
...........................................................................
id    email                       u_firstname    status(0=inactive,1=active)
...........................................................................
1     varunjoshi919@gmail.com      varun              active
2     abc@gmail.com                abc                inactive
```

After this,i have to apply searching on this table suppose if i write
ac or any starting letter of user status then we will get the list of all the active users.

**I need this Output when i type ac on search box for active user record**

```
...........................................................................
    id    email                       u_firstname    status(0=inactive,1=active)
    ...........................................................................
    1     varunjoshi919@gmail.com      varun              active
```

I have tried the below query but it is not giving any record.

```
SELECT `id`,`email`,`u_firstname`,case u_status when '0' then 'inactive' when '1' then 'active' end as status FROM `users` where `u_status` like 'ac%'
```

Comment: You can't use aliases in the WHERE clause and why don't you just use 0 and 1 in your program logic???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ( Your Query ) t
WHERE t.status LIKE 'ac%' -- for active
//WHERE t.status like 'in%' -- for inactive
```

The `%` wildcard basically say : Nothing or everything instead of the sign.

```
actkfkd LIKE 'ac%' -- TRUE
atcdas  LIKE 'ac%' -- FALSE
ac      LIKE 'ac%' -- TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter your first query's result :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT `id`,`email`,`u_firstname`,case u_status when '0' then 'inactive' when '1' then 'active' end as status FROM `users`) a
where `status` like 'ac%'
```

Comment: the above query showing the error  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Fixed it by naming the derived table ```a```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use alias `status` not the original `u_status` column.

```
`SELECT `id`,`email`,`u_firstname`,
case u_status when '0' then 'inactive' 
              when '1' then 'active' end as status 
FROM `users` 
where `status` like 'ac%'
```